# If I share a file descriptor with another process using SCM_RIGHTS, is there any way to know when it's been closed?

Tags: linux, file-descriptor

The question mostly says it all. I have one process that is opening file descriptors for use by another one on my Linux system. After opening the descriptor, it is passed over a Unix domain socket to the client process using `SCM_RIGHTS`. There are some other resources in my server process (the one that is opening the descriptor) that I would like to clean up when the client is done with the file descriptor. Is there any mechanism by which I can get notified when the client closes its copy of the file descriptor?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: You should implement some communication between the processes so it can notify you.

Comment: Does it matter whether the server keeps a copy of the FD it sent to the client open itself?

Comment: Are the FD's of regular files on a regular filesystem, or something more exotic like sockets?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica No, the server doesn’t need the FD once it has been passed to the client. The descriptors are sockets, though.